# HttpClient SendAsync ответ в непонятной кодировке

Tags: c#, .net, https

Есть сайт. Обращаюсь к его AJAX методу. Метод выполняется (то, ради чего он выполнялся произошло), но вот ответ я расшифровать не могу.

Если отправлять запрос через расширение в браузере, ответ виден нормально.

Вот как должен выглядеть ответ:

> {"win":1,"imgid":0,"bal":"950.02837137","error":0,"result":"OK"}

Вот как выглядит ответ, если я отправляю запрос в шарпе:

> \u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0003�V*��S�2�Q��M�LQ�2�QJJ�Q�R�45�30�0674�P�QJ-*�/\u0002K\u0017�\u0016��(Y)�{+�\u0002\0\0\0��\u0003\0a\t\u07bd@\0\0\0

Все заголовки я ставлю такими, какими они уходят непосредственно со страницы сайта.

Ответ приходит с пометкой charset=utf8, на что шарп ругался. Ругаться перестал после того, как я ручками подправил его на UTF-8. Но при переводе в строку получается ерунда (см выше)

Comment: Видимо, все-таки где-то заголовки отличаются...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я проверял. Мне даже приходят все те же заголовки, что приходят при отправке в браузере. Да и функция на сервере отрабатывает. Может, тут что то связано с https? Может, расшифровывается сообщение не правильно?